# C++ template class type declaration with one more template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have come across the declaration below

```
template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
class basic_istream;
```

My doubt is: what is the purpose of the dependent `class traits = char_traits<charT>` part, when we could declare the whole thing with just

```
template <class charT, class traits >
```

If by using the latter we confirm to allow any type as second template argument, then why should we go for the other one?

Comment: The "other one" is a default value

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
 basic_istream<char, char_traits<char> >;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
template<class T = Something>
```

You declare a template parameter `T` with a default argument - that is, for which an argument may or may not be provided. If it is not provided, `Something` is used. But you can still provide it explicitly to make it something else.

So with the declaration

```
template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
class basic_istream;
```

The writer of `basic_istream` allows you to declare something like `basic_istream<SomeCharT>`, without having to bother providing a second template argument, and having a sensible one calculated for you. But they still allow you to say `basic_istream<SomeCharT, SomeOtherCharTraits>` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

> By declearing above type we confirm to allow any type then why should we go for other one

In both cases we allow any type for second template parameter (`traits`) but in first case we give also a default value if the second type in unexpressed.

So, defining,

```
template <typename A, typename B = int>
class foo;
```

an object of type `foo<std::string, int>` can be declared in both the following ways

```
foo<std::string>       f0;
foo<std::string, int>  f1;
```

If you declare `foo` without default value for the second template parameter

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class foo;
```

you can only declare a `foo` object explicating both template parameter

```
// foo<std::string>       f0; <-- error now
foo<std::string, int>  f1;
```